# MyEtherWallet shows custom token but etherscan does not show any transaction?

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet, ico, etherscan

Yesterday I participated in an ICO. I sent ETH to the correct contract adress and my transaction was confirmed. I also found my transaction on  the ICO contract adress via etherscan. I then added a custom token in MyEtherWallet and the correct amount of tokens did show up. So far so good. I checked my token transfers via etherscan but any new transfer is listed. If I check the ICO adress via ethplorer it shows no transfers yet and also only three token holders. How can that be? Why do I see tokens in MyEtherWallet? Do I have the tokens or not? 
I am happy about any information.

Answer (score 1):

yes you have the tokens. Happenened to me aswell. Patience is King.

Comment: I found a workaround which I have not tried yet but seems to solev the proplem: https://blog.drhack.net/how-to-add-evn-token-on-etherscan-ethplorer/   but it does not solve or explain the underlying problem. Would still be intersted in why that problem appears.